# Gridview displaying infinite repeating item

Tags: android, gridview, android-cursoradapter

When I load my app it should display 20 movie poster in a 2 column 10 row gridview. But for some reason when i keep scrolling it will keep loading up the same 20 posters, so pretty much infinite scrolling. Still new to android development so any help will be great!

**MovieAdapter**

```
public class MovieAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
        super(context,c,flags);
    }

    private String convertCursorRowToUXFormat(Cursor cursor){
        String poster = cursor.getString(MainActivityFragment.COL_MOVIE_URL);
        return poster;
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,Cursor cursor,ViewGroup parent){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.poster_image, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


        final String POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
        final String POSTERIMAGE_SIZE = "w500";

        ImageView posterImage = (ImageView)view;
        final String POSTERIMAGE_URL = POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL + POSTERIMAGE_SIZE + convertCursorRowToUXFormat(cursor);

        Picasso.with(context).load(POSTERIMAGE_URL).into(posterImage);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Poster Urls: " + POSTERIMAGE_URL);


    }

}
```

**MainActivityFragment**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private static final int MOVIE_LOADER = 0;

    private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String[] MOVIE_COLUMNS = {
//            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID,
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER
    };

    static final int COL_MOVIE_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_MOVIE_URL = 1;

    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(),null,0);

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movieposter_image_gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(cursor != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                            .setData(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI);

                startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Selected item position " + position + ", with id: " + l);
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(MOVIE_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void updateApplication() {

        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask(getActivity());
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String sortBy = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sort_by_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_popular_default));
        movieTask.execute(sortBy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateApplication();

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle){
        Uri movieUri = MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
        movieUri,
        MOVIE_COLUMNS,
        null,
        null,
        null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor){
        mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader){
        mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }





}
```

**FetchMovieTask**

```
public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();


    private final Context mContext;

    public FetchMovieTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private boolean DEBUG = true;

    private void getMovieDataJSON(String movieJSONStr, int result)
            throws JSONException {

        final String MDB_RESULT = "results";
        final String MDB_POSTER = "poster_path";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_PLOT = "overview";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_RATING = "popularity";
        final String MDB_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";

        try {
            JSONObject movieJSON = new JSONObject(movieJSONStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJSON.getJSONArray(MDB_RESULT);

            Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<>(movieArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                String poster;
                String title;
                String plot;
                String rating;
                String releaseDate;


                //Get theJSON object representing the movie
                JSONObject movieDetail = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);

                poster = movieDetail.getString(MDB_POSTER);
                title = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_TITLE);
                plot = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_PLOT);
                rating = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_RATING);
                releaseDate = movieDetail.getString(MDB_RELEASE_DATE);

                ContentValues movieDetailValues = new ContentValues();
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME, title);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER, poster);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_PLOT, plot);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING, rating);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_REDATE, releaseDate);

                cVVector.add(movieDetailValues);
            }
            int inserted = 0;

            if (cVVector.size() > 0) {
                ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
                cVVector.toArray(cvArray);

                inserted = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FetchMovieTask Complete. " + inserted + " Inserted");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground (String...params){

            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String movieJSONStr = null;
            int result = 20;

            try {

                final String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("api_key", BuildConfig.MOVIE_API_KEY)
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                movieJSONStr = buffer.toString();
                getMovieDataJSON(movieJSONStr, result);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

**MovieProvider**

```
public class MovieProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // The URI Matcher used by this content provider.
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private MovieDbHelper mOpenHelper;

    static final int MOVIE = 100;


    static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher(){

        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = MovieContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

        matcher.addURI(authority,MovieContract.PATH_MOVIE, MOVIE);

        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate(){
        mOpenHelper = new MovieDbHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri){

        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match){
            case MOVIE:
                return MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(("Unknown uri:" + uri));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                        String sortOrder) {

        Cursor retCursor;

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)){

            case MOVIE: {
                retCursor = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                        MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
                break;
            }

            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
        return retCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri;

        switch (match) {

                case MOVIE: {
                    long _id = db.insert(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
                    if(_id > 0)
//                        returnUri = MovieContract.MovieEntry.buildMovieUri(_id);
                            returnUri = MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI;
                    else
                        throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                    break;}


            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        db.close();
        return returnUri;
        }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        int rowsDeleted;

        if (null == selection) selection = "1";
        switch (match){

            case MOVIE:
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,selection,selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        }
        return rowsDeleted;
    }
    @Override
    public int update(
            Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        int rowsUpdated;

        switch (match){

            case MOVIE:
                rowsUpdated= db.update(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        }
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri,ContentValues[] values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case MOVIE:
                db.beginTransaction();
                int returnCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (ContentValues value : values) {
                        long _id = db.insert(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,value);
                        if(_id != -1) {
                            returnCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
                return returnCount;
            default:
                return super.bulkInsert(uri,values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(11)
    public void shutdown() {
        mOpenHelper.close();
        super.shutdown();
    }



    }
```

Comment: I did a quick fix by adding " LIMIT 20" to my Cursor query in my MovieProvider class. MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 20",

Answer (score -1):

Use [RecyclerView](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/) instead of GridView